# In org-mode, a function to export to HTML file AND open?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In org-mode, if I do `org-export-dispatch`, then choose `Export to HTML`, I can then choose `As HTML file and open`. Four keystrokes though.

I'd like to reduce this to a single keybinding. However, I don't see a function to export to HTML file AND open the file in a browser. I see only the function `org-html-export-to-html`, which does not open the file.

How can I export to HTML and open the file with a single keybinding?

Comment: As you say, `C-c C-e h o` the first time `C-u C-c C-e` the next time.  You can see the underlying Emacs Lisp by searing for `:menu-entry` in `ox-html.el`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a direct function for this, but you could achieve what you want using `org-export-to-file`, the last argument of which is a "post-processing" step:

```
(org-export-to-file BACKEND FILE &optional ASYNC SUBTREEP VISIBLE-ONLY BODY-ONLY EXT-PLIST POST-PROCESS)
```

The post-processing step is handed the path to your new file; you could use something as straight-forward as `find-file`:

```
(defun org-html-export-to-html-and-open 
  (&optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
  (interactive)
  (let ((outfile (org-export-output-file-name ".html" subtreep)))
    (org-export-to-file 'html outfile async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist #'find-file)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "whatever you fancy") 'org-html-export-to-html-and-open)
```

Comment: Thanks! This opens the `.html` file in Emacs. But the desired behavior is to launch it in a browser, which is what happens if I do `org-export-dispatch`, then choose `Export to HTML`, then choose `As HTML file and open`.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. This part, then, will be somewhat context dependent. My approach would be to shell out to a command which will open the file (since you have the path on hand) -- on OSX/macOS you could use the `open` utility, for instance. Does that make sense?

Comment: what would that look like in the function?